# Conditional return statement in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create nested folder (folder design made with CSS) with all files of that folder inside it. And if the file does not have any folder it should appear without folder.

> allsrc - contains the blob of image
>
> nodeRes - contains the filepath which comes from backend nodejs server
>   like /folder/for/file/abc.jpg
>
> dirloc - contains an object with key getpath and value folder path
>   /folder/for/file/ excluding filename, key dirnames and value folder
>   names.

As you can see **return** statement, all files are shown inside a folder even if the file is not in any folder.
I don't want any file without folder to be shown inside a folder.

Is there any easy way of doing it such as any available file tree package or my code can be improved?

```
 class Load extends Component {
      constructor({props, token}) {
        super(props, token);
        this.state = { 
            isToggleOn: true,
            allsrc: ['blob:http://localhost:3001/ee2fec36-36fa-4858-8cb1-0c9d83417ace', 'blob:http://localhost:3001/cd32fb1c-b0d1-44ed-ae49-5fec1eac59a7'],
            nodeRes: '/folder/for/image/abc.jpg',
            dirloc: [ { getpath: '/folder/for/image', dirnames: 'image' },
                      { getpath: '/folder/two', dirnames: 'two' ],
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

        handleClick() {
            this.setState({ isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn})
      }

  findkeys(dirkey) {
      dirkey.map((d) => {
      return d.dirnames
    })
  }

      render() {
        const { allsrc, nodeRes, dirloc } = this.state;

         return (
             allsrc !== '' ?
                allsrc.map((p, i) => (
                  dirloc === '' ? 
                    <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} key={nodeRes[i]} className='tc' onClick={() => { this.handleClick() }}>
                      <div id='images'>
                        <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc' alt='robots' src={ p }/>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    : <div className='container' key={ this.findkeys(dirloc) }> 
                      <div className="folder">
                        <div className="folder-inside">
                          <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} key={nodeRes[i]} className='tc' onClick={() => { this.handleClick() }}>
                            <div id='images'>
                              <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc' alt='robots' src={ p }/>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>))
                : null
                );
      }
    }
```

Comment: "As I can see..."? Nope, can't; the code is quite difficult to read, and seems to include unrelated code to boot.

Comment: @DaveNewton I m sorry, i had no idea which code was irrelevant to post here so i have pasted everything. Can u only check 'return' statement?

Comment: Which `return` statement? There are several. It's also impossible to "check the `return` statement` without knowing what data is being operated on, and what the expected return value is.

Comment: There is a logical problem, which is solvable if we know the relation between allsrc, dirloc and nodeRes. I would propose, you create a tree data structure after you have fetched the data, then push that tree structure in your state and render based on the tree. This will help you isolate your concerns and make it easier for you to find the problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you pls recheck? I have updated my question. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: @dubes I have tried to update my question, pls check again.

Comment: based on the data you provided in state: this line in your render: `dirloc === '' ? ` will never be true for _any_ entry in your allsrc. That is why all images will be put inside a _folder_ 
From your requirements, it seems like you want to loop over files/folders, then create a tree view. So perhaps allsrc shouldn't be at the top of your loop

Comment: nodeRes is a file path that comes from backend nodejs server and then the file path is used to fetch the file from backend.

Comment: If datastructures have you down, take a look at the source of some OSS examples https://react.rocks/tag/TreeView

Comment: @dubes can u pls show an example of how to render ?